# Conga Composer - Run a Macro

Tags: excel, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Wondering if anyone has found a way to have a macro run in an excel template being generated out of Conga Composer. They explicitly state on their website that Macros will not run when the Excel is generated as a PDF but wanted to see if anyone has found a way around this.

I've tried Worksheet_Change and Workbook_Open as potential workarounds as they do not require a button press to trigger a macro but they do not seem to work. I assume Conga's process might not open the file or it just disregard's macros completely when printing a PDF

Answer (score 0):

So for security reasons, Conga Composer does not ever allow for macros to execute as part of a merge process.  This is due to the potential of someone embedding malicious code inside of a macro that could be executed during a merge operation.  As the former PM for Composer, I sincerely doubt we would lift this restriction.